# Isn't there an installer package for Oracle Database?

Tags: database, oracle, metapackages

I wish I could install Oracle Database as easy as possible using Ubuntu Software Center or apt-get install.

I suggest that at least, someone of the community, could create a package that installs it dirclty from their website or from a pre-downloaded files by the user their selves.

Just like: googleearth-package
"utility to automatically build a Debian package of Google Earth"

Comment: Another database engine is not an option? There are so many alternatives.

Comment: I need that for my Study :) So it is not an option right now. But I prefer MySQL though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question: No.

There are no packages to install Oracle database servers. And probably will never be: if Oracle licensing for Java doesn't allow it to be hosted in the main repositories, it should be even more restrictive regarding Oracle DB.

Also the creation of "metapackages" (ie: a package that downloads and install it) should be hard to achieve, since even to download Oracle Express Edition you need to have an Oracle account.